# Compley SQL Query

Tags: sql-server

I have the following sql query where i am getting the following output [image: Actual Output]

I am having different rows for same product because now i am doing transaction from two different terminal.
I need my output result be like [image: Expected Output].

I need to sum the qty sold,weight,chiffre_Daffaire_Caisse,qty retour,montant retour.
I have tried to sum the field but it is not working i am having several rows.
At end i need only one product desc per row

Please help.

```
 With CTE as (
 SELECT RTRIM(substring(D.F1056, patindex('%[^0]%',D.F1056), 10)) as 
 Shop_Number,
 REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), D.F254, 103), '/', '') AS Todays_Date,
 SDP_TAB.F03  as Rayon,
[SDP_TAB].F04 as Famille,
RTRIM(D.F01) as Barcode,
RTRIM(D.F01) as Barcode2,
[POS_TAB].F02 as Descriptn,

CASE 
WHEN D.F1034=3 THEN  REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), 
CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,3),D.F64), 111), '.', '')
                            ELSE 0 
END as Qty_Sold,


CASE 
WHEN D.F1034=3 THEN convert(DOUBLE PRECISION,  D.F67)
                            ELSE 0 
END as Weight,

0 as qte_remisse_caisse,
0 as montant_remisse_caisse,

CASE
WHEN QTY.F1034=3011 THEN QTY.F64 
WHEN QTY.F1034=3012 THEN QTY.F64 
                            ELSE 0 
END as Qty_retour,

CASE
WHEN REF.F1034=3011 THEN (convert(DOUBLE PRECISION,  REF.F65) * 100 ) 
WHEN REF.F1034=3012 THEN (convert(DOUBLE PRECISION,REF.F65) * 100 )
                            ELSE 0 
END as Montant_retour,


 CASE WHEN [POS_TAB].F81 = 1 THEN REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), 
 CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),  Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), 
 Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),D.F65/NULLIF(D.F64,0)) as nvarchar) * cast(1.15 
 as numeric(10,2)) ) as nvarchar) ), 111), '.', '')  ELSE
 REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), 
 Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),D.F65/NULLIF(D.F64,0)) as nvarchar) ), 111), 
 '.', '')
 END as UnitPrice


 FROM 
             [dbo].[RPT_ITM_D] D
             LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[RPT_ITM_D] REF ON (D.F01=REF.F01 AND 
             D.F254=REF.F254 AND D.F126=REF.F126 AND D.F1056=REF.F1056 AND 
             D.F1057=REF.F1057 AND REF.F1034 IN (3011,3012))
             LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[RPT_ITM_D] QTY ON (D.F01=QTY.F01 AND 
             D.F254=QTY.F254 AND D.F126=QTY.F126 AND D.F1056=QTY.F1056 AND 
             D.F1057=QTY.F1057 AND QTY.F1034 IN (3011,3012))
             LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[POS_TAB] ON (D.F01=POS_TAB.F01)
             LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].SDP_TAB ON (POS_TAB.F04=SDP_TAB.F04)
             LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo]. DEPT_TAB ON (SDP_TAB.F03=DEPT_TAB.F03)

  where 
             -- Removed code 3011
             D.F1034 IN (3,3012)
           --  D.F1034 IN (3,3012,3011)
               AND
             D.F254  = '2017/09/19' 


             )

           SELECT
           Shop_Number,
           Todays_Date,
           Rayon,
           Famille,
           Barcode,
           Barcode2,
           Descriptn,
           Qty_Sold,
           Weight,
          ((Qty_Sold * UnitPrice)/100) AS chiffre_daffaire_Caisse,
          qte_remisse_caisse,
          montant_remisse_caisse,
          Qty_retour,
          Montant_retour,
          (UnitPrice * 10) as UnitPrice

         FROM CTE
```

Comment: First know your database your are probably are using MS-SQL or SQL-server and not MySQL.because [dbo] is a invalid database in MySQL

Comment: @RaymondNijland its SQL Server

Comment: Should the third product be 9000 qty sold? It still shows 4000 in your example.

Comment: @DrHouseofSQL Updated, thx

Comment: is that your current query which is returning the results above?

Comment: This looks like you need to use some basic aggregation here. SUM the columns you want for totals and group by the rest of them.

Comment: @scsimon yes it is returning the above result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure that all you need is to use SUM for the columns you want totaled. Something like this.

```
SELECT
    Shop_Number
    , Todays_Date
    , Rayon
    , Famille
    , Barcode
    , Barcode2
    , Descriptn
    , Qty_Sold = SUM(Qty_Sold)
    , Weight = SUM(Weight)
    , SUM((Qty_Sold * UnitPrice)/100) AS chiffre_daffaire_Caisse
    , sum(qte_remisse_caisse) as qte_remisse_caisse
    , sum(montant_remisse_caisse) as montant_remisse_caisse
    , sum(Qty_retour) as Qty_retour
    , sum(Montant_retour) as Montant_retour
    , sum(UnitPrice * 10) as UnitPrice
FROM CTE
GROUP BY Shop_Number
    , Todays_Date
    , Rayon
    , Famille
    , Barcode
    , Barcode2
    , Descriptn
```